# Forest admin in Rails 6: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS] "/forest")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, forestadmin

I tried to use [Forest Admin](https://www.forestadmin.com/) in a Rails app. Followed their installation guide and I get this error and Forest doesn`t recognize my app. What should I do?

```
Started OPTIONS "/forest" for ::1 at 2021-05-02 11:05:50 -0300
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS] "/forest"):
actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:36:in `call'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.0.3.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
railties (6.0.3.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
railties (6.0.3.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:82:in `call'
webpacker (4.3.0) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (6.0.3.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:527:in `call'
puma (4.3.7) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
puma (4.3.7) lib/puma/server.rb:713:in `handle_request'
puma (4.3.7) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (4.3.7) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
puma (4.3.7) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You need to put code fences (`\`\`\`) on a separate line in order for the formatting to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error is not that Forest is not recognizing your app, but that your app does not know the route `OPTIONS /forest`.

Someone reported having the same problem as you here in the [Forest Admin community forum](https://community.forestadmin.com/t/rails-6-app-model-changes-do-not-show-in-forestadmin/2233/10). In this case, it was an issue with the file `config/initializers/forest_liana.rb` that was not correctly deployed.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've manage to install it again and fixed it.